# Closing holes in solid mesh (not surface)

Tags: mesh, edit-mode

I have a mesh with a **lot** of holes. However the mesh is not just a surface, it has 2 sides and I would like to preserve the **volume**.

[image: Illustration of the holes]

*Right now I would probably for each hole just delete one loop and then fill 2 loops around somehow, which is a lot of work.*

Is there a better way to close them?

Comment: use an object to boolean then sculpt a bit with the smooth brush?

Comment: I'll try that, thanks @moonboots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say this is your mesh:

[image]

Create an object that will be your bandage, boolean it with your inital object:

[image]

Go into *Sculpt* mode, choose the *Draw* brush, put the *Strength* at 0, enable *Dyntopo*, sculpt, it will make the shape merge:

[image]